# Why a div inside a div moves instead of centering when applied div align center

Tags: html, css

The other day I managed to post some text inside a colored div and with a bit of digital washi tape (like cellotape) on top. However, now I wanna fully understand the code.

They help me a bit, but even though it worked perfectly, I don't really understand why it's done that way and what some things mean. I'd like to fully understand everything written there so next time I don't need help ;)

Here would be the code:

```
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div style="background-color: #fcfaf9; box-shadow: 3px 4px 8px #DBDBDB; margin: auto; padding-bottom: 25px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 25px; padding-top: 35px; width: 70%;">
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 215px;">
<img src="http://bit.ly/Washi-tape-rosa" style="margin: -70px auto 0; position: absolute; width: 215px;" />
</div>
<u><b><i>Ingredients:</i></b></u><br />
<br />
2 big zuchinni grated<br />
1 egg beaten<br />
1/4 cup almond flour<br />
1 tsp sea salt<br />
1 tsp black pepper<br />
</div>
```

1) I get the outer div is the beige "background" with the shadow. I understand all the code there

2)

I think that if I had tried to do it myself, I had just written

3)

3.a) I don't get how to specify the margins:

- I get I can do margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 5px; etc.
- If I write margin: 5px; that means there's a margin of 5 everywhere (right, left, top...).
- margin: 0 auto; is 0 on top and bottom and auto on right and left
- What if I want to only specify top and bottom?
- why sometimes (like here) says three values? What is margin: -70px auto 0;?

3.b) What is position: absolute?

(Yes, I have read about it, absolute, relative, but I didnt really understand the difference)

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

**a.** What if I want to only specify top and bottom?

```
.selector{
     margin-top:10px;
     margin-bottom:10px;
 }
```

**b.** why sometimes (like here) says three values? What is `margin: -70px auto 0;`?

```
.selector{
    margin:-70px auto 0
} 
/*margin-top:-70px, margin-left:auto, margin-right:auto, margin-bottom:0*/
```

To understand it properly introduce yourself with [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

[image]

**c.** What is `position: absolute`?

-- absolute: The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.  [Read more..](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Hope this help.!

Answer (score 0):

- You can specify margin top and bottom by using `margin-top:` and `margin-bottom` in your css.
- With margin and padding, when three values are present they represent top, left-and-right, and bottom. So `margin: -70px auto 0` would be `margin-top: -70px`, `margin-right: auto`, `margin-bottom: 0`, `margin-left: auto`

As for absolute vs. relative positioning:

**Absolute Positioning:** is taken out of the flow of the document, and gives you access to the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties. It is postioned *absolutely* relative to its nearest positioned ancestor, which is the nearest element that has a `position: absolute` or `position: relative`, etc. defined. The big thing is that it's taken out of the flow of the document [like this](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position$samples/Absolute_positioning?revision=921635).

**Relative Positioning:** lays out the element as it would normally be laid out in the document as if it were un-positioned, then adjusts the element's position accordingly without changing the layout, [more like this](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position$samples/Relative_positioning?revision=921635).

Note that there some other positioning options as well, such as static (which is an element's normal behavior) and fixed (which keeps an element where it is, even as you scroll).

Comment: Okay, so the margins I can either write them separetely or all together in one line. If in one line: (a) if there's one value means it's the same one for all four, (b) if there's two values it's first top and bottom and then right and left, and (c) if there's three values, it means the first is the top one, the second right and left, and the third the bottom. Is that correct?

Comment: Here's a great resource if you'd like to learn more:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#Syntax